# Showing data in view files while sending mails

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to send mails to users upon registration, In view file i need to send the details submitted by users in the form. When i tried to send mails data is not getting passed. Please help me to solve out the issue

First i run the following command

```
php artisan make:mail WelcomeMail
```

After that under `Mails/WelcomeMail.php` i wrote following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;


class WelcomeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        //return $this->from('xavierissac94@gmail.com')->subject('new customer registration')->view('emails.welcome');
       return $this->view('emails.welcome');
    }
}
```

Following is the code in my registration controller

```
public function storeUsers(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ]);

    $postdata = $request->all();
    $user = new User;
    $hashedRandomPassword = Hash::make('password', [
        'rounds' => 12
    ]);
   $user = new User;
   $user->name=$postdata['user_name'];
   $user->email=$postdata['email'];
   $user->password= $hashedRandomPassword;
   $user->save();
    $data = array( 'email' => $postdata['email'], 'name' => $postdata['user_name'] );

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
   return back()->with('success','thanks for contacting us');
   exit(ok);
    //Mail::to($postdata['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
    return $user;
   //return redirect('users');
}
```

Following is the my code in view file, here am trying to get the data using `{{$user['name']}}`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome Email</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Dear {{$user['name']}}  </h2>

<p>You have succesfully registerd as a valuable client of LifeLove and Other things. We are sending you a password to login.Please remeber to change your password after login.</p>
<p>Your Password for login is {{$user['password']}} </p>
<p><h2>Kind Regards,</h2></p>
<h2>Team Life Love</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

But i am getting undefined variable  `$user` error. I need to send the password and usernames to user upon registration. Mails are sending succesfully but data is not passing.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the public `$user` property in your mailable class:

```
class WelcomeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    // ADD ME!!!!
    public $user;

    // ADD ME TOO!!!!
    public $password;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user, $password)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
       return $this->view('emails.welcome')->with(['password' => $this->password]);
    }
}
```

> Typically, you will want to pass some data to your view that you can utilize when rendering the email's HTML. There are two ways you may make data available to your view. First, any public property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view. So, for example, you may pass data into your mailable class' constructor and set that data to public properties defined on the class

[Mailable docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#view-data)

You'll also need to update your mailable view file to use object accessor notation rather than array indices. For example:

```
// BAD
<h2>Dear {{$user['name']}}  </h2>

// GOOD
<h2>Dear {{ $user->name }}  </h2>
```

Comment: Updated the answer to support sending the password. Just remember to pass it in the constructor of the mailable in the controller like you're doing with the user object.